# Как правильно пишется название грузовика "Краз"?

Tags: орфография, аббревиатуры

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется модель грузовика "краз"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно: *Завод выпускает грузовики КрАЗ*. Аббревиатуры (КрАЗ — Кременчугский автомобильный завод) в кавычки не заключаются.

Подробнее на [Грамоте.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273123).

Answer (score 0):

**Официально пишется так: КрАЗ-255Б** — советский тяжёлый грузовой автомобиль-вездеход с колёсной формулой 6 × 6 (одна из марок автомобиля).

При этом довольно часто встречается  неофициальное названия **КРАЗ**, а иногда разговорные варианты Краз и краз, например: **КРАЗы наматывают бездорожье на колеса!**

Answer (score 0):

***Кр***еменчугский **А**втомобильный **З**авод им. 50-летия Советской Украины (Полтавская область). Основан в 1958 году на базе комбайнового завода; с 1976 года — головное предприятие объединения "**АвтоКрАЗ**". Выпускает грузовые автомобили большой грузоподъёмности. В 1971 году завод был награждён Орденом Ленина.
*Международная аббревиатура — **KRAZ**.*  Именно она находится на "морде" автомобиля.
На "бочине" может быть и КРАЗ, и KRAZ.
[**КрАЗ**](http://www.autokraz.com.ua/index.php/ru/)

Профессиональные  водители часто говорят:  "КРАЗуется",  "КРАЗуля", "КРАЗотка"...
В настоящее время это:  *самосвалы, бортовые, седельные, тягачи, лесовозы и сортиментовозы ,* *спецтехника, военные автомобили.*..
Одни названия ***"чего"*** стоят(!):
***КрАЗ-Халк, КрАЗ-Фиона, КрАЗ-Кугуар дизель, КрАЗ-Ураган, КрАЗ-Спартан,  KрАЗ-6322 Raptor, КрАЗ-Шрек-М, КрАЗ-6322 «Мастер», КрАЗ-6322 «Солдат», КрАЗ-63221 «Мост»,  KRAZy Crocodile, КрАЗ-5173РЕ"Самум"...***
 [**KRAZy Crocodile**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHBOFHlYxOw)